# Android Studio - if file exists in system folder then

Tags: java, android

It's my first project in java.
I want to add wallpaper backup/restore functionality to my app.

Code to backup:

```
public void btnBackupWallpaper(View view) {
    File wallpaper = new File("/data/system/users/0/wallpaper");
    if(wallpaper.exists()){
        RootCmd.RunRootCmd("cp -f /data/system/users/0/wallpaper /data/local/tmp/wallpaper");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper backup completed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper not found.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Code to restore

```
public void btnRestoreWallpaper(View view) {
    File wallpaper = new File("/data/local/tmp/wallpaper");
    if(wallpaper.exists()){
        RootCmd.RunRootCmd("cp /data/local/tmp/wallpaper /data/system/users/0/wallpaper");
        RootCmd.RunRootCmd("chmod 0700 /data/system/users/0/wallpaper");
        RootCmd.RunRootCmd("chown system.system /data/system/users/0/wallpaper");
        RootCmd.RunRootCmd("rm /data/local/tmp/wallpaper");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper restore completed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper backup not found.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Restore working fine, but backup always says "Wallpaper not found".

```
File wallpaper = new File("/data/system/users/0/wallpaper");
    if(wallpaper.exists()){}
```

Why is this part of code doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that `/data/system/users` is accessible by `~`. You should run the check with root

Comment: Thanks for replay. I do run my app with root. If You mean "~/data/system/users/0/wallpaper", this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use RootTools:

```
public void btnBackupWallpaper(View view) {
    if(RootTools.exists("/data/system/users/0/wallpaper")) {
        RootCmd.RunRootCmd("cp -f /data/system/users/0/wallpaper /data/local/tmp/wallpaper");
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.wallpaper_backup_completed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.wallpaper_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```